# How can I stop a <script> tag in HTML from being executed?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script tag in my HTML page like following:

```
<code>
     <script>alert("This is a test");</script>
</code>
```

The thing is I have to include the three lines above and show it to the user. However, every time I refresh the page, the alert statement gets executed and an alert window pops up. I need to show the script statement in my HTML to the users. But, I don't want it to be executed. 
What can I do to disable the script from being executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`:

```html
<code>
  &lt;script&gt;alert("This is a test");&lt;/script&gt;
</code>
```